# str_replace not replacing correctly

Tags: php, parsing, replace, str-replace

I have the following, simple code:

```
$text = str_replace($f,'<a href="'.$f.'" target="_blank">'.$u.'</a>',$text);
```

where $f is a URL, like `http://google.ca`, and $u is the name of the URL (my function names it 'Google').

My problem is, is if I give my function a string like

```
http://google.ca http://google.ca
```

it returns

```
<a href="<a href="http://google.ca" target="_blank">Google</a>" target="_blank">Google</a> <a href="<a href="http://google.ca" target="_blank">Google</a>" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

Which obviously isn't what I want.  I want my function to echo out two separate, clickable links.  But str_replace is replacing the first occurrence (it's in a loop to loop through all the found URLs), and that first occurrence has already been replaced.

How can I tell str_replace to ignore that specific one, and move onto the next?  The string given is user input, so I can't just give it a static offset or anything with substr, which I have tried.

Thank you!

Comment: It's not that `str_replace` is replacing incorrectly, it's just that you're misusing it. (Anal, but true.) :-)

Comment: Yeah, I know.  I was wondering if there was any other way to make it work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, though it's a bit of a kludge: you can use a temporary marker that (hopefully) won't appear in the string:

```
$text = str_replace ($f, '<a href="XYZZYPLUGH" target="_blank">' . $u . '</a>',
                     $text);
```

That way, the first substitution won't be found again. Then at the end (after you've processed the entire line), simply change the markers back:

```
$text = str_replace ('XYZZYPLUGH', $f, $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass your function an array of URLs, instead?

```
function makeLinks(array $urls) {
    $links = array();

    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        list($desc, $href) = $url;
        // If $href is based on user input, watch out for "javascript: foo;" and other XSS attacks here.
        $links[] = '<a href="' . htmlentities($href) . '" target="_blank">'
                 . htmlentities($desc)
                 . '</a>';
    }

    return $links; // or implode('', $links) if you want a string instead
}

$urls = array(
    array('Google', 'http://google.ca'),
    array('Google', 'http://google.ca')
);

var_dump(makeLinks($urls));
```

Comment: That's basically what I'm doing now.  A foreach loop to loop through each already 'found' URL and translate it into a link.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem correctly, you can just use the function sprintf. I think something like this should work:

```
function urlize($name, $url)
{
    // Make sure the url is formatted ok
    if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
        return '';

    $name = htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES);
    $url  = htmlspecialchars($url, ENT_QUOTES);

    return sprintf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $url, $name);
}

echo urlize('my name', 'http://www.domain.com'); 
// <a href="http://www.domain.com">my name</a>
```

I havent test it though.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use preg_replace instead of str_replace here like this code:

```
$f = 'http://google.ca';
$u = 'Google';
$text='http://google.ca http://google.ca';
$regex = '~(?<!<a href=")' . preg_quote($f) . '~'; // negative lookbehind
$text = preg_replace($regex, '<a href="'.$f.'" target="_blank">'.$u.'</a>', $text);
echo $text . "\n";
$text = preg_replace($regex, '<a href="'.$f.'" target="_blank">'.$u.'</a>', $text);
echo $text . "\n";
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<a href="http://google.ca" target="_blank">Google</a> <a href="http://google.ca" target="_blank">Google</a>
<a href="http://google.ca" target="_blank">Google</a> <a href="http://google.ca" target="_blank">Google</a>
```